# coffescript for the Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm using the gem gmaps4rails and getting the error when I check the developer tools.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined
```

I have read over the other solutions on here and Know that the problem is how the script is loading before the window.

here is the initializer code (stores.js.coffee)

```
gm_init = ->
  gm_center = new google.maps.LatLng(53,6)
  gm_map_type = google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  map_options = { center: gm_center, zoom: 8, mapTypeId: gm_map_type }
  new google.maps.Map(@map_canvas, map_options)

map = gm_init()
```

I have taken some of the tips and adviece that the other questions have given me but have been unable to fix the code, I think this line should fix the code.

```
window.onload = ->
```

I have placed this line, and others in various places in my code but I have had no success. I'm new to ruby on rails and coffeescript, I know the solution is relatively simple. I'm just having difficulty correctly implementing this fix.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Does not know CoffeScript. Is this line `new google.maps.Map(@map_canvas, map_options)` transformed to `return new_map_obj`?

Comment: This code was generated by the gem so I'm unsure, sorry.
there are 2 other pages generated by the gem also but they are very long.

Comment: this is definitely not code from gmaps4rails, this is raw google maps

Comment: I must have installed the gem and then used Google maps to generate the code instead of making use of the gem.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I understand the issue: you're not giving your map a place to live.

I'd bet `@map_canvas` is undefined.

(why dont you use gmaps4rails if you already have the gem installed?)

Comment: shouldn't I get an uninitialized constant if that's undefined?
The map runs perfectly, But I just want to get rid of those nasty errors that you can see when you open up the dev tools

Comment: you already have `Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    `window.onload = (-> map = g.init() )`

If you still get the error try and find what object is undefined.